# Подсчитать количество фраз в массиве php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [warehouse_id] => 11111111111111[product_id] => 105757633 [offer_id] => A2275 [updated] => [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => SKU_STOCK_NOT_CHANGE [message] => sku stock not changed ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [warehouse_id] => 11111111111111[product_id] => 105760010 [offer_id] => A1143 [updated] => [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => SKU_STOCK_NOT_CHANGE [message] => sku stock not changed ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [warehouse_id] => 11111111111111[product_id] => 105761741 [offer_id] => A2585 [updated] => [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => SKU_STOCK_NOT_CHANGE [message] => sku stock not changed ) ) )
```

Как подсчитать сколько раз встречается фраза sku stock not changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo substr_count(json_encode($array), 'sku stock not changed');
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо большое!